# Using Non English character resulting in unexpected error in Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Well this is weird let me describe the scenario

I have this mailer define for my rails application

```
class DeliveryMail < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def document_upload_mail(user,document)
     @user = user
     @document = document
     mail(:to => user.email ,:subject =>  "Envió de enlace descarga documentos resultados domain") do |format|
      format.html { render "upload_file" }
     end
  end
end
```

Now the problem is this spanish text

```
Envió de enlace descarga documentos resultados domain
```

Whenever I set this as subject of the mail

```
:subject => "Envió de enlace descarga documentos resultados domain"
```

This is the error  Rails prompt with my console

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

Now If I remove the text "`Envió`"  Rails dont throw any error and mail get delivered

Just to Let you know I not missing any syntax any where

pasting the mail code

```
class DeliveryMail < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def user_creation_mail(user,password)
    @user = user
    @password = password
    mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "Congratulation you been registered in Domain") do |format|
      format.html { render "user_creation" }
    end
  end


  def document_upload_mail(user,document)
     @user = user
     @document = document
     mail(:to => user.email ,:subject =>  "Envió de enlace descarga documentos resultados domain") do |format|
      format.html { render "upload_file" }
     end
  end
end
```

Not Sure what wrong with these

I created a **dummy rails application** to check to see I the same behavior is shared across

and **Yes** I found the same error in this application as well

My Rails version is

3.2.1

Ruby version

1.9.2-p290

Sure there is something wrong can anyone guide me on this

Comment: Even `"Envió".force_encoding("UTF-8")` does not solve the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Just put `coding:` in your first-line comment and then after an optional whitespace specify the encoding of the rest of your file. You can put extra explanation here, like:

```
# I will use the following encoding: utf-8. Till the end of the file.
```

See? `coding:` part is here, so it works.

Comment: @Viren This is a magic comment. It specifies the encoding of your file.

Comment: I thought you where asking me of putting these as hash in `ActionMailer configuration` . that comment help  just wanted to know more on it could you please share me any link on it

Comment: @Viren I've read it in a paper book about Ruby. But there is not that much to explain further. Just put `couding:` in your first-line comment and then after optional whitespace specify the encoding of the rest of your file. You can put extra explanation here, like: `# I will use the following encoding: utf-8`. See? `coding:` part is here, so it works. And the encoding stuff here is case insensitive.

Comment: @Viren Is I said, it's a paper book. I can't link to it :) If you're interested, it's called 'Programming Ruby 1.9: The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide'.

Comment: Also wanted to know y this error was not reported  when `rails boots the application`

Comment: @Viren If you're in development mode, then Rails won't load each of your file at the app start. Contoller/models and other stuff you put in your 'app' folder will be loaded lazily, only when they needed. The drawback here is that you newer know if all your files are valid. But with decent test coverage this isn't a problem.

Comment: Sure I was expecting this answer just wanted to check thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Put this at the very top of your `DeliveryMail` class. Or anywhere else the special characters are present.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

I had a similar problem with Chinese characters in my app and adding this line of code fixed the problem for me.

Comment: which file mailer view file or deliver_mailer.rb file

Comment: got it I could not understand that your answer is a `ruby comment` and not `ruby hash`